# RxJava - Any way to combine scan and flatMap?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Let's say I have a function that takes a `String` and a `long` and returns a `Single<String>`.

```
Single<String> stringAddition(String someString, long value) {
  return Single.just(someString + Long.toString(value));
}
```

Now I have this `Observable`...

```
Observable.interval(1, SECONDS)
  .scan("", (cumulativeString, item) -> {
    // Need to return the result of stringAddition(cummulativeString, item)
  });
```

I'm at a loss on how to do this. Scan needs me to return a `String`, but II would like to use the method that returns a `Single<String>`. To me it seems like I need something that can combine the behaviour of both `scan` and `flatMap`. Is there any RxJava2 wizardry that can help me?

Comment: Why do you return `Single<String>` in the first place?

Comment: I was trying to come up with a simple example for a problem that's much more complex in context. In my current project it's actually a web service request of `Single<Response>`.

Comment: I now realise my example is actually too trivial to correctly demonstrate the problem I'm trying to solve. If I scan using `Single<Response>` as the accumulated value then I actually end up executing every request twice :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve it as follows. This can be somewhat shortened if `stringAddition` would have returned `Observable`

```
Observable<String> scanned = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .scan(
                    Observable.just(""),
                    (cumulativeString, item) ->
                        cumulativeString
                          .flatMap(str -> stringAddition(str, item).toObservable())
            )
            .flatMap(it -> it);
```

Comment: This answer does indeed work for my trivial example. I think however this answer ends up subscribing to each `Single<String>` twice; once in the `flatMap` inside the scan and again in the outer `flatMap`.

Are you able to think of any solutions that involve not having the `Single<String>` subscribed to twice?

Comment: I mean, I guess I could use `.cache()` on the `Observable` produced by `scan` and that should work, but I feel like there should be a neater way!

Comment: This is a bit late, but I think you can get the desired effect by using `replay(1)` rather than `.cache()`. 

There's another approach in C#, but I'm not sure if it's applicable to java. You can return a `Task` rather than an observable and in scan await the accumulated value, then return the new value. Tasks cache their value and return it when awaited